# can not make autohosted app work

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have created a simple autohosted app, I chose a Office 365 Team Site when I created it in VS 2012.

However it generates

> The parameter 'token' cannot be a null or empty string

when I choose deploy in VS.

I have searched on google a lot and I changed the value of `AppPrincipal` element in `manifest.xml` from `AutoDeployedWebApplication` to `Internal`.

Now when I deploy it, I am getting invalid url `~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx` instead. What is the problem? And why is the token empty?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the latest version of the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 [here](http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012) and re-create your app project using them.

This error was due to a misconfiguration of the default autohosted app template in an earlier release of the tools (I actually believe it was resolved in Preview 2, but I just confirmed it works with the latest production release).